# What does two input and one output buffer like gate do?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Reading through my textbook, I found the circuit of DRAM, and I can't get one part of it. It looks like that in one cell configuration as well.

My **question** is: what does two input and one output buffer produce? I know that buffer passes the data it got from one end and outputs to the other end without modifications. Am I correct that this is indeed a buffer and not some other gate of the circuit?

P.S. there are some other gates before the read/notwrite, but I decided to omit them, since they don't seem to be relevant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuSQ13.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's a transmission gate: the read/write# controls whether or not the output is driven. In read, the output is "off" and no current flows through the buffer.

Comment: @MarkU, so its something like a D latch? The behavior seems to match perfectly. Also, is my question off topic or wrong in any way? If its wrong I can just delete it, but if not, I would want to accept the answer if you post it.

Comment: Look up 74HCT125, you can get 4 of them in one IC package

Comment: Actually 74HC126 is more like it

Comment: @vicatcu, it is sequential output gate, if I recall correctly. It shifts one bit after the other from input to output, and also has some latch features. Yeah, it looks like that, just 4 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [tri-state buffer](https://logic.ly/lessons/tri-state-buffer/). When the control signal (Read/NotWrite) is high, the data signal is propagated from "Data In" to whatever is connected to the right. When it is low, there is a virtual disconnect between "Data In" and the output of the buffer. In case of DRAM it might be used to select a function of the data pin to be either input or output.

Answer (score 2):

That is a tri-state buffer.  The Read/notWrite input turns the output of the buffer off or on.  These are normally used to between the data output of a memory, and a databus.

If the Read/notWrite control line is High, the buffer works normally to pass data.  With the control line Low, the output stage is off, effectively disconnecting the memory from the databus.